# Laravel - Pivot table with 3 models realtionships Many to Many and One to Many

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I want to make authentification in my Laravel project for Users who have Roles and Permissions. Actually That's not a problem to do but Users can create Teams or be invited member of any team and each User in any Team has his ONE Role in the team(in another team the user may have another role). In essense Users must have many Roles but only one role in one particular Team and I can't understand if I create correct DB relationships.

Please check the image with relationships to get more info:
[image: Database relationships here]

In general:

1. Users have many Teams, and Teams have many Users(Many to Many)
2. Teams have many Roles, Roles have many Teams (Many to Many)
3. Users have many Roles, **But only one Role in a Team** what relationship should be there?

I'm interested how to do that properly. How to minimize messy code in the future and avoid of need to redesign DB relationships.

Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do need a polymorphic relationship: 
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types
with a morph map. 
https://nicolaswidart.com/blog/laravel-52-morph-map

Comment: Hey Luis, thanks! but User has One Role in a particular Team. I think User_Role_Team should have one Role, so relationship should be One to One. I do not know how to do that actually with Pivot table. Polymorphic relationship seems to just maintain 2 different models in one table, so it's not suitable option for me

Comment: In the graphic the relation between user_role_team and roles is 1 to 1. I tink that the relation is many to one. You need an inverse relation to get information from roles. You have many register user-role-team. But you have a limited roles. You can have many user-team with the same rome. But this is just an idea.